# Regular expression hangs - Java matcher

Tags: java, regex, string

String:

> Aqua, Sodium Laureth Sulfate, Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Dimethicone, Cocamide MEA, Zinc Carbonate, Glycol Distearate, Sodium Chloride, Zinc Pyrithione, Sodium Xylenesulfonate, Cetyl Alcohol, Parfum, Guar Hydroxypropyltrimonium Chloride, Magnesium Sulfate, Sodium Benzoate, Ammonium Laureth Sulfate, Magnesium Carbonate Hydroxide, Linalool, Butylphenyl Methylpropional, Limonene, Hydroxyisohexyl 3-Cyclohexene Carboxaldehyde, Benzyl Alcohol, Hexyl Cinnamal, Citronellol, Tocopheryl Acetate, Paraffinum Liquidum, Sodium Polynaphthalenesulfonate, CI 19140, DMDM Hydantoin, CI 15510, Methylchloroisothiazolinone, Disodium EDTA, Tetrasodium EDTA, Methylisothiazolinone.

Current Regex:

```
System.out.println(string.matches("([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W]*)+"));
```

Java application hangs up. I can't find the error in the RegEx. By googeling I found out that this could be called "catastrophic backtracking"!? 
The Regex should match the String if it only contains uppercase words
if for example 1 word is lower case in should not match it.

Comment: What is your expected output?
What happens when you simplify the input?

Comment: true if all words in the source starts with a uppercase character. False if there is a lowercase character. I think the "3-" in the string has been the cause. Still I don't get why this cases that infinitive calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you split your input string by word and then pattern match it, event simpler: not to pattern match if you just want to test that the first letter of each word is uppercase, like:

```
for (String s : string.split("\\W")) {
  if (s.charAt(0) < 'A' || s.charAt(0) > 'Z') {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Sounds a lot faster to me (and you can even have the word that failed if you need).

Comment: It is most definitely faster than eternity :)

Comment: Thanks, we use hibernate validation engine. It would be a big effort to add a custom validation, anway I got it working with this regex:
string.matches("([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W\\d]*)+")

It seems like when a number after a word comes it was not working anymore. So I added the "\d".
Any idea why this caused the "hang/infinitive evaluating" of the thread?

Comment: @user1635689: You have nested quantifiers (`(...[\\W\\d]*)+`). These will often lead to an exponentially increasing number of permutations that the regex engine needs to check before declaring failure.

Comment: what regex do you recommend: 1) see source string above = expected true, 2) Test, Test, Test = expected true 3) Test, test, Test expected false 4) N/A expected true

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you had in mind was

```
String regex = "([A-Z][\\d\\w]+( [A-Z][-\\d\\w]+)*, )*[A-Z][-\\d\\w]+( [A-Z][-\\d\\w]+)*\\.";
System.out.println(string.matches(regex));
```

returns true.

The problem you have with the regex is that its overly complicated. The disadvantage with adding expressions until you get `true` is that it can match things you didn't have in mind.

```
Random rand = new Random();
while(true) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[40];
    rand.nextBytes(bytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) bytes[i] &= 0x7F;
    String string = new String(bytes, 0);
    if (string.matches("([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W\\d]*)+"))
        System.out.println(string);
}
```

prints things such as

```
"^;%XX`'SwJ|[*4"*0C<Tgbom_. \^
{PvU_y9aJSm?08EL(   NpfA9a[:$YbN8VTtMk
;![`LR7Yy\AO5PZ@X4}GajC<*XvKE11
8l5W6*IDNH[9C'@.>7`LHsCN*,{26O}
EFJ5MBVxi%W_t6v54EmLmgjFvqyYh\<"
+7]|ULh2[MT`Yx{MKH4N
'8p!2mf
```

whereas the expression I gave matches

```
KfhBuGv7, S3.
IWzu, XHop4Z.
LJbXfrd, PdR.
V2dxQV, LA9z.
HKf37cy0, TS.
RAw2E5a, Ajs.
Up-, GPQ7 I_.
```

Comment: Return false. Could you explain the approach a bit?

Comment: I got it working with this regex:
string.matches("([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W\\d]*)+")

It seems like when a number after a word comes it was not working anymore. So I added the "\d".
Anyone has an explanation why this caused the "hang/infinitive evaluating" of the thread?

Comment: @user1635689 Try it without `Hydroxyisohexyl 3-Cyclohexene Carboxaldehyde`. Your regex won't match one-character words, and `-` is not a word character. If it works without that string, perhaps the regex `"([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w*\\b[\\W]*)+"` would do the trick.

Comment: `-` is in the "words" of the sample string. I don't know of any chemicals with a one letter name. ;)

Comment: Ok, i see. Even though as mentioned above it workd fine with "\d": "([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W\\d]*)+"

Comment: I understand that "Hydroxyisohexyl 3-Cyclohexene Carboxa" caused it. But still I don't have an explanation for the hang?!

Comment: The problem with your regex is that it returns true even for this: Zinc carbonate while correct is Zinc Carbonate

Comment: @user1635689 Ok, fixed that. When regular expressions get particularly complicated, I think its worth using a parser instead as this way you can say exactly what each part does. ;)

Comment: hmm I still get false for e.g. "Test, Test, Test", so still not working for me :( any idea why? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I can't see where you are even checking for single `,` I would use regular Java code as at least you can debug it. ;)

Comment: hhm the framework we use is hibernate validation. They offer a pattern constraint. A custom constrain would impact a lot of changes & new deployments. Anyway, thanks for some ideas!