# Memory leak issue in small java program

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, email-validation

We are using the below code to verify our email address, but when we enter a long email address to test it, the CPU utilization goes 100% and program keeps on running, can you identify the issue.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class EmailAddress1 implements Serializable {


private static final boolean ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS = true;


private static final boolean ALLOW_QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS = true;


private static final String wsp = "[ \\t]"; //space or tab
private static final String fwsp = wsp + "*";

private static final String dquote = "\\\"";

private static final String noWsCtl = "\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x7F";

private static final String asciiText = "[\\x01-\\x09\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x7F]";

private static final String quotedPair = "(\\\\" + asciiText + ")";


private static final String atext = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\*\\+\\-\\/\\=\\?   \\^\\_\\`\\{\\|\\}\\~]";
private static final String atom = fwsp + atext + "+" + fwsp;
private static final String dotAtomText = atext + "+" + "(" + "\\." + atext + "+)*";
private static final String dotAtom = fwsp + "(" + dotAtomText + ")" + fwsp;

private static final String qtext = "[" + noWsCtl + "\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E]";
private static final String qcontent = "(" + qtext + "|" + quotedPair + ")";
private static final String quotedString = dquote + "(" + fwsp + qcontent + ")*" + fwsp + dquote;

private static final String word = "((" + atom + ")|(" + quotedString + "))";
private static final String phrase = word + "+"; //one or more words.

private static final String letter = "[a-zA-Z]";
private static final String letDig = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
private static final String letDigHyp = "[a-zA-Z0-9-]";
private static final String rfcLabel = letDig + "(" + letDigHyp + "{0,61}" + letDig + ")?";
private static final String rfc1035DomainName = rfcLabel + "(\\." + rfcLabel + ")*\\." + letter + "{2,6}";

private static final String dtext = "[" + noWsCtl + "\\x21-\\x5A\\x5E-\\x7E]";
private static final String dcontent = dtext + "|" + quotedPair;
private static final String domainLiteral = "\\[" + "(" + fwsp + dcontent + "+)*" + fwsp + "\\]";
private static final String rfc2822Domain = "(" + dotAtom + "|" + domainLiteral + ")";

private static final String domain = ALLOW_DOMAIN_LITERALS ? rfc2822Domain : rfc1035DomainName;

private static final String localPart = "((" + dotAtom + ")|(" + quotedString + "))";
private static final String addrSpec = localPart + "@" + domain;
private static final String angleAddr = "<" + addrSpec + ">";
private static final String nameAddr = "(" + phrase + ")?" + fwsp + angleAddr;
private static final String mailbox = nameAddr + "|" + addrSpec;

private static final String patternString = ALLOW_QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ? mailbox : addrSpec;
public static final Pattern VALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(patternString);

private String text;
private boolean bouncing = true;
private boolean verified = false;
private String label;

public EmailAddress1() {
super();
}

public static boolean isValidText(String email) {
return (email != null) && VALID_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
String addy =       "1234567asjdkasdjflaslkdjfkajdfhklsadjfhsdkljfhksadjf8901234@askdjfaskdjbfskldjbgfskdjfksdjfklsadjfksadjfkasdjfkasdjfkasjfksdjfskadjfbsdkjbfasdkjasdkjbfksdjf6789012345678901.com";
if (isValidText(addy)) {
System.out.println("Valid email address.");
} else {
System.out.println("Invalid email address!");
}
}
}
```

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: try to see on what step the CPU is 100% also from the description this is not a memory leak issue .

Comment: Use the [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) rather than writing one manually.

Comment: [Probably a case of catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: I cannot specifically answer as to why you are getting the hang, but it is occurring when it gets to the Matcher.matches() method call inside of your 'isValidText()' method. My thinking is that it has something to do with infinite backtracking. I believe [this thread can shed more light on the issue for you:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194456/regular-expression-hangs-java-matcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, this regex is badass ! Look at it with a little bit of formatting :

```
(
 (
  (
   [ \t]*[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+[ \t]*)
  |(
      \"(
    [ \t]*(
            [\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]|(
                \\[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F])
          )
    )
      *[ \t]*\")
 )
 +)
?[ \t]*<(
        (
         [ \t]*(
             [a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+(
                 \.[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+)
             *)
         [ \t]*)
        |(
            \"(
    [ \t]*(
            [\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]|(
                \\[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F])
          )
    )
            *[ \t]*\")
        )
@(
        [ \t]*(
            [a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+(
                \.[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+)
            *)
        [ \t]*|\[(
            [ \t]*[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x21-\x5A\x5E-\x7E]|(
                \\[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F])
            +)
        *[ \t]*\])
>|(
        (
         [ \t]*(
             [a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+(
                 \.[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+)
             *)
         [ \t]*)
        |(
            \"(
    [ \t]*(
            [\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]|(
                \\[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F])
          )
    )
            *[ \t]*\")
  )
@(
        [ \t]*(
            [a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+(
                \.[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?   \^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+)
            *)
        [ \t]*|\[(
            [ \t]*[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x21-\x5A\x5E-\x7E]|(
                \\[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F])
            +)
        *[ \t]*\])
```

This is not a memory leak problem. Your regex is just too complex to be matched easily. You program will eventually return a valid result, but only once every valid possibility have been tried.

You should use [Apache Commons EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html), It will be much faster and reliable.